# Pen pressure doesn't work in Blender on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: uv, sculpting

I'm using a XP-PEN deco03 (awesome tablet by the way). It works perfectly in blender when i'm on windows but pressure sensivity isn't transmitted when I'm on Ubuntu.

I've confirmed that it works the way it should in Krita using Ubuntu 18.04 so I don't think it is HW, OS or Driver related.

Anybody got an Idea?

Thanks

Comment: Try File/load Factory Settings it should just "work"

Comment: No it doesn't. At all.

Was it for making sure a plugin wasn't interfering?

Thanks Anyway

Comment: yep, afraid i have nothing else. My Pen(wacom) either works in Linux or not. Seems very odd to have a situation where it works but not completely and only in Blender. It is not going to help but does it working in GIMP and Inkscape in Linux?